# Get access to a variable method to end threading loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have question about how to call some variables, in this case from the method inside `exportCsv` that belongs to `back_Gui` class. I want to use the variables `self.msg_` and `self.opstat` in the method `__update` from class `_Gui` to stop the reproduction of the gift and promt out the window to save the file. When I run the code and press the button it iterates in an infinite loop because the variable is not passing to. Also, I try to aggregate some threading to not to freeze the window when the button is pressed. Any solution?.
Also, I think these variables I mention would be inside the `try` but what happens in the except?. Do I have to create more variables to avoid infinite looping on the gift?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import threading


class back_Gui: #Superclass
'''Class that handle the data'''
   def __init__(self, db_name = 'database.db'):
       self.db_name = db_name
       self.msg_ = None
       self.opstat = None
    .
    .
    .

  def exportCSV(self):
      df_to = self.df
      try:
          export_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv')
          df_to.to_csv(export_file, index=False, header=True)
      except:
          pass
      
      #These are the variables that I need
      self.msg_ = "Done."
      self.opstat = -1

class _Gui(back_Gui): #Subclass
   def __init__(self, window):
      '''Gui of the windw tk '''
      self.wind = window #child
      super().__init__()

      self.text_font = ('Helvetica', '10', 'bold')
      self.Button_(self.wind)

   def Button_(self, wind):
    """Run the gift while the csv is being generated"""
      #Button
       b1 = Button(self.wind, text="random", 
                font=self.text_font, 
                command=self.job_genCsv,
                ).grid(row=1, column=5, padx=5, pady=5 ,sticky=W)

   def frame_maps(self, wind):
      '''Frame Containter'''
       self.frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='Hail Hydra', font=self.text_font, height = 500, width = 1300, bd=4)
       self.frame.grid(row=2, columnspan=20, sticky=W+E)#, columnspan=3, padx=25, pady=25)
    
       # create the canvas, size in pixels
       self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width=1300, height=500, bg='white')
       # pack the canvas into a frame/form
       self.canvas.grid(row=0, columnspan=20, sticky=N, ipadx=20, ipady=20)#
       # load the .gif image file
       #Here it has to be use the self because is local variable

       self.current_image_number = 0


       file="cain.gif"
       info = Image.open(file)
       self.frames = info.n_frames

       self.gif1 = [PhotoImage(file=file, format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(self.frames)]
    
   def __update(self):
       #self.job_genCsv()
       ''' update the gift '''
       self.frame.update_idletasks()#update
    
       if self.opstat >= 0.0:
          #msg = self.image_on_canvas #

          # next image
          self.current_image_number += 1

          # return to first image
          if self.current_image_number == self.frames: #len(self.images):
              self.current_image_number = 0

          # change image on canvas
          self.canvas.itemconfig(self.update, image=self.gif1[self.current_image_number])
                   

          _ = threading.Timer(0, self.__update).start()
          print("loop")
       else:
          if self.msg_ == "Done.":
              self.update = self.canvas.create_image(250, 50, anchor=NW, image=self.gif1[self.current_image_number])
          del self.msg_
          #control variable restablished
          self.opstat = 0
          print("ends")

   def job_genCsv(self):
      '''Runs his job and call frame_maps '''
      self.frame_maps(self)
      _ = threading.Timer(0, self.exportCSV).start() 
      _ = threading.Timer(0, self.__update).start() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = _Gui(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Documents\run.py", line 214, in __update
    if self.opstat >= 0.0:
AttributeError: '_Gui' object has no attribute 'opstat'
```

Comment: Did you consider passing the variables into the method as parameters?

Comment: how?. From the `__init__` in back_Gui?. Can you explain me? @NicholasHunter

Comment: `__update` has access to all the class variables, including `self.opstat`.  Do you realize that you are starting TWO new copies of `__update`in every loop, once with `self.frame.after` and once with `threading.Timer`?  That's exponential growth which will overwhelm your computer.  Use one or the other.

Comment: Now I got it, and do you know how to stop the loop before the `asksaveasfilename` displays? @TimRoberts

Comment: What loop?  You don't have any loops here.

Comment: `__update` is not gettin the variables that´s why appear that error. And the loop I mean the gift that iterates and never stops. @TimRoberts